# Jenkins in Docker doesn't have access to /dev/vboxnetctl for VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, docker, jenkins

I'm trying to set up Jenkins (runs in Docker; official image) which runs as user "jenkins". And Jenkins should start a virtual machine using docker-machine and virtualbox.

I bind-mounted /dev/vboxnetctl into the jenkins container. And I also tried to use sudo to run docker-machine as root.

But the user jenkins does not have access to /dev/vboxnetctl:

```
$ docker-compose exec jenkinsmaster sudo docker-machine create test
Creating CA: /root/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem
Creating client certificate: /root/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem
Running pre-create checks...
(test) Image cache directory does not exist, creating it at /root/.docker/machine/cache...
(test) No default Boot2Docker ISO found locally, downloading the latest release...
(test) Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v17.09.0-ce
(test) Downloading /root/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v17.09.0-ce/boot2docker.iso...
(test) 0%....10%....20%....30%....40%....50%....60%....70%....80%....90%....100%
Creating machine...
(test) Copying /root/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /root/.docker/machine/machines/test/boot2docker.iso...
(test) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(test) Creating SSH key...
(test) Starting the VM...
(test) Check network to re-create if needed...
(test) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: /usr/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif create failed:
(test) 0%...
(test) Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
(test) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(test) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: Operation not permitted
(test) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(test) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(test) 
(test) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
```

How to get this working?

Comment: does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186672/117549) help?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I couldn't find a way like that in Docker but I found this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#devices But this didn't help, too.